# How to stop WhatApp for Linux sending empty audio when not active?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

This is not a Bluetooth question as such – the culprit is WhatsApp for Linux ("WAfL" for short) – but Bluetooth is the affected service.

Bluetooth sources:

1. Ubuntu Studio 23.10, including WhatsApp for Linux v.2.2411.2, on a vanilla Xeon E3-1225 PC.
2. OnePlus 8T mobile phone.

I'm using Bose QuietComfort QC35 Bluetooth headphones. Like many other Bluetooth headsets, they can connect to two audio sources at any time. However, if one is actively sending, the other is disregarded.

The problem is this: even when WAfL does not have anything to send – there is no video or audio playing – it is constantly sending zero-volume audio, as shown in its icon:

[image: WhatsApp for Linux icon, showing sub-icon for active audio output]

This unnecessarily prevents my mobile phone from being able to send audio to my headphones.

If it's possible to configure WAfL not to maintain active audio output when it doesn't have audio to send, I would appreciate any assistance or information about that configuration. Alternatively, if there is a support page for WAfL, I'd appreciate a pointer to it, as my Google-fu is clearly lacking today.